# .htaccess RewriteRule : redirects http to https always (works fine), but 1 exclusion is still needed...

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Seems like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

works perfect and redirects all http requests to https pages. 
As result,

```
http://mydomain.com/?p=abc
http://mydomain.com/?q=de
http://mydomain.com/?z=123
http://mydomain.com/
```

go to https://

```
https://mydomain.com/?p=abc
https://mydomain.com/?q=de
https://mydomain.com/?z=123
https://mydomain.com/
```

respectively.

How to keep `http://mydomain.com/` stay with no redirection to https?
Criteria: if no parametres (no ?p, no ?q, no ?z etc.), then stay at http.

Thank you

Comment: do you mean to say you want to use `https` only if there are parameters passed?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay on HTTP when the query string is empty, use solution #1 below.

If you only want to keep HTTP when p, q, or z params are present, comment out the #1 solution and uncomment out the #2 one.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#1 if query string is not empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
#2 only if p or q or z params are not present
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)(p|q|z)= [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```